# CSS inline Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I previously was using this code:
**My questions is how to set the tooltip to show up inline (to the right) with the parent div instead of above.**

Thanks for looking it over

easier to read jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SAYnZ/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">START.
    <div id="tooltip">GOOD  LUCK !</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
cursor: pointer;
position: fixed;
text-transform: uppercase;
background: #39AC9B;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: "Gill Sans", Impact, sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
top: -webkit-calc(50% - 50px);
left: -webkit-calc(50% - 137px);
padding: 16px 25px;
text-align: center;
width: 250px;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* webkit flicker fix */
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* webkit text rendering fix */
}

#wrapper #tooltip {
 background: #1496bb;
 bottom: 100%;
color: #fff;
display: block;
left: -25px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
opacity: 0;
padding: 20px;
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
-webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
 -moz-transform: translateY(10px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(10px);
   -o-transform: translateY(10px);
      transform: translateY(10px);
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
 -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
   -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
      transition: all .25s ease-out;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
 -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
   -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
}

#wrapper #tooltip:before {
 bottom: -20px;
 content: " ";
 display: block;
 height: 20px;
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
   }  

#wrapper #tooltip:after {
border-left: solid transparent 10px;
border-right: solid transparent 10px;
border-top: solid #1496bb 10px;
bottom: -10px;
content: " ";
height: 0;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -13px;
position: absolute;
 width: 0;
  }

#wrapper:hover #tooltip {
opacity: 1;
pointer-events: auto;
-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
 -moz-transform: translateY(0px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0px);
   -o-transform: translateY(0px);
      transform: translateY(0px);
 }
```

Comment: do you mean to say that you want that tooltip to come exactly above that div?

Comment: Sorry I will clarify, I would like the tooltip to show up to the right of the parent div. The wording is just for example sake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SAYnZ/5/), just set

```
#wrapper #tooltip {
...
    top: -3px;
    left: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 15px;
...
```

and make triangle point to right direction

Answer (score 1):

Make the bottom=20% in your #wrapper #tooltip.
Check your Fiddle. Have Updated it.
Sorry if its not what you want

Comment: Anytime. I thought u wanted it above.